# SSH permission denied using smartcard authentication

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, macos-highsierra, smartcard

Our institute recently adopted smartcard/chip and PIN logins for all computers on the network. Ever since, I have been unable to log in to any of our Linux network hosts via SSH from my Mac (OSX High Sierra).

The command that works for all other Mac users I've encountered on the same network is as follows:

ssh -o PKCS11Provider=/usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib hostname

But for me, the server returns "permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

This is the same error that other users get when they try to log into a Linux network server without their smartcard inserted into the reader. However, my smartcard seems to be working fine for all local logins.

Note - I am able to log in to the same Linux server (using smartcard and PIN) if I'm doing so as a local user.

The system admin assures me that the server firewall is open to my IP address (on port 22) and is correctly configured for remote ssh logins, so the problem apparently lies with my Mac. I'm at a loss for how to troubleshoot this as there is so little information out there on smartcard ssh login issues, so any assistance or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the server's  /etc/ssh/ssh_config file changing

```
> Host *.local
```

to

```
> #Host *.local
```

This will prevent the server from checking if login is from the local domain.